# Adding new site to my GA account. No one has a login but GA code is in the source code

Tags: properties

I am trying to gain access to a client's GA account. No one seems to have the admin login info. I see the GA code on the website. How can I get access to the GA account, or add to my existing GA account? Or do I just need to create new code and add to site?

Comment: What does GA stand for?

Comment: @Rose Google Analytics maybe?